# I need to create an Oracle query listing my table names followed by column names

Tags: oracle11g

Do you know how to create an Oracle query that will list my table name, followed by all the column names in that table? I have 5 tables in total.

Something like:
**Table**
Column1
Column2
Column3
**Table2**
Column1
**Table3**
Column1
Column2

Comment: Are you trying to get a result with a single column that will have either a table name or a column name?  You could do that but it would seem very odd.  If you want a result with two columns, you can simply `select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns` assuming you are logged in as the owner of the tables.

Comment: Yes, all in one column. It is odd I agree.  Sorry. Just like the example i posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hard-pressed to imagine why you would want a single-column result that doesn't do anything to differentiate between what is a column name and what is a table name.  You can do something like

```
select pseudo_column_name
  from (
      select table_name, table_name pseudo_column_name, 0 column_id
        from user_tables
      union all
      select table_name, column_name, column_id
        from user_tab_columns
)
order by table_name, column_id
```